# Unable to deploy cube (.bim) files using CI CD

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, cube, azure-analysis-services, azure-service-principal

I'm trying to automate the Tabular cube files deployment to Azure Analysis services using CI-CD Azure DevOps. I have used the "Azure Analysis Service" plugin by Jan Pieter Posthuma.

I have a .bim file which contains the metadata of the tabular cube,
then created a CD pipeline which utilizes the .bim file and deploying it to the target (Azure Analysis Services)

I have provided my Portal Azure credentials for the following as AAS dont have separate username and password:

1. Analysis Services Username - xxxx
2. Analysis Services Password - xxxx

But while deploying it I'm facing the following error:

> [error]Error during deploying the model (Unable to obtain authentication token using the credentials provided. If your Active Directory tenant administrator has configured Multi-Factor Authentication or if your account is a Microsoft Account, please remove the user name and password from the connection string, and then retry. You should then be prompted to enter your credentials.)

This is becoming a headache. Did a bit of R&D, but no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: PS: My account is a microsoft account, but we cant remove the username and password as those are mandatory fields

Answer (score 1):

Since the account has MFA configured, you cannot use named user authentication.
You need to use service principal authentication wherein you create a service principal/app in Azure AD and add it as Analysis services admin.

This should work as we too leverage the same process